# Replacing urllib2 modules with Requests

Tags: python-3.x, python-requests, urllib2

I am trying to get the stocks live data and corresponding to it plot the same using python.
In a tutorial I learnt that they are using `urllib2`and i got to know through stack overflow that its been suspended due to issues and the best alternative is `requests`.

Following is the code segment using `urllib2`. Please suggest me the exact alternative for `requests`:

```
    def GetQuote(self, symbols=['AAPL','GOOG']):
    '''This method gets a real-time stock quote from the nasdaq website.'''

    # Make sure the quoteList is a list
    if type(symbols) != type([]):
        symbols = [symbols]

    # Create a string with the list of symbols
    symbolList = ','.join(symbols)

    # Create the full query
    url = self.kBaseURI % symbolList

    # Make sure the URL is formatted correctly
    self.url = urllib2.quote(url, safe="%/:=&?~#+!$,;'@()*[]")

    # Retrieve the data
    urlFile = urllib2.urlopen(self.url)
    self.urlData = urlFile.read()
    urlFile.close()

    # Parse the returned data
    quotes = self._ParseData(self.urlData)

    return quotes
```

Answer (score 0):

You haven't given the entire code, but whatever I interpret, I'll convert it. There is just 1 or 2 lines you need to change. The code is in Python 3. Make sure to import `requests`.

```
def GetQuote(self, symbols=['AAPL','GOOG']):
        '''This method gets a real-time stock quote from the nasdaq website.'''

        # Make sure the quoteList is a list
        if type(symbols) != type([]):
            symbols = [symbols]

        # Create a string with the list of symbols
        symbolList = ','.join(symbols)

        # Create the full query
        url = self.kBaseURI % symbolList

        # Make sure the URL is formatted correctly
        self.url = requests.utils.requote_uri(url)

        # Retrieve the data
        urlFile = requests.get(self.url)
        self.urlData = urlFile.content

        # Parse the returned data
        quotes = self._ParseData(self.urlData)

        return quotes
```